# ZendFramework 2 SQL Statement execute to return array of objects

Tags: database, zend-framework2

I'm trying to figure out how to have the `execute` method of an ZF2 SQL Statement class to return an array of objects rather than an array of arrays. The documentation/reference seems to lack severely in this area and the code isn't documented properly.

This is what I have (I'm using the PDO MySQL driver but that should not be relevant):

```
$sql = new Sql( $db );

$query = $sql->select()
   ->from('users')
   ->where('id > 1');

$stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject( $query );
$results = $stmt->execute();
```

`$results` is now an array of arrays but I need it to be an array of objects instead. How can I specify this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that most people use doctrine for ORM
http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not looking for an ORM.